# SQL Query to know followed days of item sales

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with all items sold. These records are for all lines of the documents issued. Some items have daily sales and not others. Still others, who do not have daily sales, have certain periods with sales followed.

I need a query that shows me, per item, which the greatest period of sales followed (in number of days). Is this possible?

In Excel could do, using a grouped per item / day / quantity table and applying the following formula: "If amount of day = 0 then return 0, otherwise, if the previous day's amount = 0 then return 1 else return the amount of the previous day + 1". In the end it's just checking the maximum value of this column.

Any help to do this in SQL? Thank you!

Here's a small sample (period between January 1 and 10):

Original Table:

```
SalesDate   Doc ItemID  Qty  
  01-jan    156 123456  10  
  01-jan    156 654321  5  
  01-jan    157 123456  3  
  02-jan    158 654321  4  
  02-jan    158 123456  7  
  03-jan    159 123456  8  
  04-jan    160 654321  3  
  04-jan    161 654321  8  
  05-jan    162 654321  3  
  06-jan    163 123456  7  
  06-jan    163 654321  2  
  06-jan    164 123456  9  
  07-jan    165 654321  4  
  08-jan    166 123456  5  
  09-jan    167 123456  6  
  10-jan    168 123456  3  
  10-jan    168 654321  5  
  10-jan    169 654321  1
```

Intermediate Table:

```
CalendarDate ItemID SumQty FollowedSalesDays  
    01-jan   123456 13     1  
    02-jan   123456 7      2  
    03-jan   123456 8      3  
    04-jan   123456 0      0  
    05-jan   123456 0      0  
    06-jan   123456 16     1  
    07-jan   123456 0      0  
    08-jan   123456 5      1  
    09-jan   123456 6      2  
    10-jan   123456 3      3  
    01-jan   654321 5      1  
    02-jan   654321 4      2  
    03-jan   654321 0      0  
    04-jan   654321 11     1  
    05-jan   654321 3      2  
    06-jan   654321 2      3  
    07-jan   654321 4      4  
    08-jan   654321 0      0  
    09-jan   654321 0      0  
    10-jan   654321 6      1
```

Final Result:

```
ItemID  MaxFollowedSalesDays  
123456  3  
654321  4
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I'm sorry: MS SQL Server.

Comment: can you show some sample data and desired output ??

Comment: @M.Ali: Question edited - small sample added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [cursor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_%28databases%29)-based approach. It should run in linear time, making it a lot faster than the naive implementation.

```
DECLARE @ItemID varchar(10) = NULL
DECLARE @SalesDate date
DECLARE @NextItemID varchar(10)
DECLARE @NextSalesDate date
DECLARE @StartDate date
DECLARE @Contiguity int
DECLARE @MaxContiguity int = 1

DECLARE @MaxSalesDateContiguityPerItem TABLE (
    ItemID varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    MaxSalesDateContiguity int NOT NULL
)
DECLARE SalesCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT ItemID, SalesDate FROM ItemsSold ORDER BY ItemID, SalesDate

OPEN SalesCursor

DECLARE @more int = 3
WHILE @more > 0
BEGIN
    FETCH NEXT FROM SalesCursor INTO @NextItemID, @NextSalesDate
    SET @more = CASE
        WHEN @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0 THEN 0      -- reached end of result set
        WHEN @ItemID IS NULL OR @ItemID <> @NextItemID THEN 1      -- next item
        WHEN DATEDIFF(day, @SalesDate, @NextSalesDate) > 1 THEN 2  -- date hole
        ELSE 3
    END

    -- Calculate the length of the contiguity we just passed.
    -- Compare with earlier contiguities; keep whatever is longest.
    IF @more <= 2 AND @ItemID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @Contiguity = DATEDIFF(day, @StartDate, @SalesDate) + 1
        IF @Contiguity > @MaxContiguity SET @MaxContiguity = @Contiguity
        SET @StartDate = @NextSalesDate    -- begin another contiguity
    END

    -- Flush the item we just passed to the temporary table.
    IF @more <= 1 AND @ItemID IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @MaxSalesDateContiguityPerItem VALUES (@ItemID, @MaxContiguity)
        SET @MaxContiguity = 1             -- start over with another item
    END

    SET @ItemID = @NextItemID
    SET @SalesDate = @NextSalesDate
END

CLOSE SalesCursor
DEALLOCATE SalesCursor

SELECT * FROM @MaxSalesDateContiguityPerItem ORDER BY ItemID
```

**Note:** please replace all occurrences of `varchar(10)` by whatever type your `ItemID` column has.

**EDIT:** further performance considerations...
Should you be dealing with record sets that make even this linear-time solution too slow, then please note there are alternatives. In your question you already proposed an 'intermediate table'; you could make this a permanent table, to be updated either at regular intervals by a scheduled job, or immediately by a [trigger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) on your sales transaction table. The latter guarantees real-time information, but it can make the transactions slower.

Comment: Thank you @Ruud for your effort. It's a great job! I tried with some samples and results was always perfect. However applied to the production DB there is something strange - the cursor's query returns more than 42000 records, (there are more than 42000 different items with sales), but at the end result appear only 18612 ... any idea what it might be?

Comment: I'm sorry @Ruud - I forgot your note. When I changed varchar(10) to nvarchar(25) (my ItemID), it resulted for every records!Thanks again!

Comment: @PJLG: Glad it worked out! I made an edit with suggestions in case even this linear-time solution turns out to be too slow.

Comment: Thanks for your care @Ruud. After all I was surprised with performance of this query - in few seconds returns the full result. Anyway your suggestion to create a table and keep it updated with a Job is interesting. By other hand using triggers, for me, is the last solution because I don't want to affect transaction performance. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a naive implementation. Its performance is terrible (quadratic time complexity), but it may come in handy for testing a better implementation.

```
SELECT ItemID, MAX(Filled)
FROM (
    SELECT i1.ItemID,
           DATEDIFF(day, i1.SalesDate, i2.SalesDate) AS Distance,
           (
               SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT i3.SalesDate)
               FROM ItemsSold i3
               WHERE i3.ItemID = i1.ItemID
               AND i3.SalesDate BETWEEN i1.SalesDate AND i2.SalesDate
           ) AS Filled
    FROM ItemsSold i1
    INNER JOIN ItemsSold i2 ON i2.ItemID = i1.ItemID AND i2.SalesDate >= i1.SalesDate
) AS CartesianProduct
WHERE Distance + 1 = Filled
GROUP BY ItemID
```

To achieve linear time complexity, you can use a [cursor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_cursor). Alternatively, move the logic to your application server.

Comment: Thank you @Ruud. It's really very slow (it would have to analyze more than 50,000 items in millions of rows) but this is not the biggest problem. The problem is the query does not return true results . I auditioned with an item that had 180 days of sales days followed and this query only returned 21.

Comment: 180 days of continuous sales? That makes me suspicious; you never mentioned we should 'skip' public holidays. Anyway, I'd like to take the challenge; can you show me a sample record set (if possible a small one) where my query falls short?